# React JSON mapped data. Trying to pass a setState variable from mapped function will not get the latest state on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React SPA and trying to render JSON data with a filter.  I have several containers that each have a class value.  When clicking on a container, I am trying to pass a value to a setState.  When stepping out of the map function, however, I cannot get the new state change to update.

I'm assuming that the render state isn't getting updated for the state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListData from "../data/list.json";

class Levels extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { newFilter: "" };
    this.onClick = this.setFilter.bind(this);
  }

  setFilter = e => {
    console.log(e); //This returns the correct class.
    this.setState({ newFilter: e }); //This will not update
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.newFilter); //This just returns the initial state of ''
    const activeTab = this.props.keyNumber;
    let levelFilter = ListData.filter(i => {
      return i.level === activeTab;
    });
    let renderLevel = levelFilter.map((detail, i) => {
      let short_desc;
      if ((detail.short || []).length === 0) {
        short_desc = "";
      } else {
        short_desc = <p>{detail.short}</p>;
      }

      return (
        <div
          className={`kr_sItem ${detail.class}`}
          data-value={detail.class}
          onClick={() => this.onClick(detail.class)}
          value={detail.class}
          key={i}
        >
          <h1>{detail.title}</h1>
          {short_desc}
          <img src={`${detail.img}`} />
        </div>
      );
    });

    console.log(this.state.newFilter);

    return (
      <div id="kr_app_wrapper">
        <div id="lOneWrapper">{renderLevel}</div>
        <div id="lTwoWrapper"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Levels;
```

Here is the code calling in the Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Levels from './components/levels2';

import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import LevelTwo from "./levelTwo";

class LevelOne extends Component{
    render(){

        return(
            <div id="lOneWrapper">
            <NavLink to='/Level2'><Levels keyNumber={1} /></NavLink>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default LevelOne;
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. You're logging `this.props.newFilter` which is a prop that is never set!? But you're also logging `this.state.newFilter` which should be updated correctly in the render.

Comment: Thanks for that catch.  I updated the above to state instead of props.  Somewhere in my frustration, I had updated to try a different way but forgot to switch the console.log back.

Comment: While you've updated the code, the question description is still unclear on what the problem is?

Comment: I will update.  I have Div's that load based on the data in the JSON file.  They each have a class that I want to pass as a filter.  When I click on the div, The class passes to the setFilter function but will not update in my render.  I'm trying to pass a variable to filter out results based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  As pointed out in the comments, binding an arrow function is pointless but it wouldn't cause the error here, so there must be something else going on in some other part of your code.

The problem is you are trying to bind an arrow function that doesn't have an implicit `this`.  Either call `setFilter` directly (no need to bind `this` with arrow functions) or change your `setFilter` function to a regular function:

```
class Levels extends Component{
     constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {newFilter: ''};
    this.onClick = this.setFilter.bind(this);
  }


  setFilter(e) {
    console.log(e); //This returns the correct class.
    this.setState({newFilter: e}); //This will not update

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Travis.  Even with that update, I still return the original state.  I'm not sure if I'm heading down the right path, but everything I've read seems to point to a batch issue.  Is there something causing the state to not update on the render?

Comment: No, I think you are overcomplicating it unless you are doing something complex in some related code that you haven't posted.  But if you are able to see the correct object in your setFilter function then when you call setState then it will update your state appropriately.

Comment: Try this.. this.setfilter = this.setfilter.bind(this)

Comment: I updated to add my other file.  I am still not able to pass back to the render.  Maybe something in there that I didn't code correctly?

Comment: Logesh, I tried that change but still have the same result.

Comment: Using `bind` with an arrow function isn't causing the problem here.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Okay then what is causing the problem?  There is no need to bind an arrow function, so I thought that it could be causing the problem

Comment: It's effectively pointless to bind the arrow function, but it won't cause a problem here. It's unclear what the problem is because of the question's description.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.  I will update my answer to reflect that.